# how to access OSX non-storage devices from docker container

Tags: macos, docker, usb, barcode

I'm currently trying to run a USB Scale and USB Barcode scanner on a docker container hooked up to my MacBook Pro. I see how to do it on linux, by using the --device or --privileged flag, but I can't seem to figure out where exactly these devices reside on my mac since they are not storage devices. Any ideas?

Comment: sadly Docker still can't do this see https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/900